# Sort an array with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to find a way to sort an array that has dynamic keys without Lowdash. Any suggestions?

I'm trying to sort by the field `unix_start`

```
"chart": [
  {
      "Nov 24, 2020": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 0,
          "c": 0,
          "unix_start": 1606194000,
          "unix_end": 1606280400
      }
  },
  {
      "Nov 23, 2020": {
          "a": 0,
          "b": 2,
          "c": 1,
          "unix_start": 1606107600,
          "unix_end": 1606194000
      }
  },
  {
      "Nov 22, 2020": {
          "a": 0,
          "b": 0,
          "c": 0,
          "unix_start": 1606021200,
          "unix_end": 1606107600
      }
  },
}
```

Comment: If your keys will be unique, I'd nix the array and use a Object or Map. A Map maintains the order the items were inserted in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.sort`:

```js
const chart =  [
  {
      "Nov 24, 2020": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 0,
          "c": 0,
          "unix_start": 1606194000,
          "unix_end": 1606280400
      }
  },
  {
      "Nov 23, 2020": {
          "a": 0,
          "b": 2,
          "c": 1,
          "unix_start": 1606107600,
          "unix_end": 1606194000
      }
  },
  {
      "Nov 22, 2020": {
          "a": 0,
          "b": 0,
          "c": 0,
          "unix_start": 1606021200,
          "unix_end": 1606107600
      }
  },
]

const sortedArray = chart.sort((a,b) => {
  const [valueOfA] = Object.values(a);
  const [valueOfB] = Object.values(b);
  return valueOfA.unix_start - valueOfB.unix_start;
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```